# subset function is missing some values?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a dataframe, and I want to confirm that two columns match for each entry.  So I tried:

```
> nrow(subset(df, col.a!=col.b))
[1] 0
```

That seemed good to me, but then I tried to compare how many matches there were to the total number of entries in the data frame.  It seems like these numbers should be equal but they are not:

```
nrow(subset(df, col.a==col.b))
[1] 3443
nrow(df)
[1] 3453
```

Any idea what is going on here?  Why does it looked like the subset dropped 10 entries?  Thanks so much for your help.

Also, I'm fairly new to this, so please let me know if there is a better way of checking if the two columns match.

Comment: do you have `NA` values in your data set??

Comment: Yes, I just realized that is the problem.  Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: try `sum(!complete.cases(subset(df,select=c(col.a,col.b))))` and see if that matches up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`subset` automatically drops rows where the criterion is `NA`. It should always (?) be the case that

```
nrow(d)
```

and

```
nrow(subset(d, col.a!=col.b))+
nrow(subset(d, col.a==col.b))+
nrow(subset(d, is.na(col.a) | is.na(col.b)))
```

should be equal.